# How to fix Google Video indexing using vimeo?

Tags: vimeo, google-search, google-search-console

Google has rolled out the Video indexing feature recently.
For all my vimeo implementation I get the following warning:

`Google could not determine the prominent video on the page`

I noticed that Google shows me two Video URL sources

1. `https://vimeo.com/sitemap_media_redirect?video_id=VIDEO_ID` (Provided by video hosting platform)
2. `https://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID` (Source: HTML tag)

The video is implemented like this:

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: This question was closed too hastily IMHO. Maybe the reviewer was not very experienced with frontend web development? Firstly my opinion is that the two video sources problem is a red herring. I have two pages generated by the same view template and one has errors and the other doesn't. The one indexed fine has  3 video links (sitemap_media_redirect plus the video link with "&" at the end) and Google appears to index it perfectly fine.

Comment: The real problem here is "Google could not determine the prominent video on the page". According to Vimeo's official advice you need to ensure your video is above the fold and takes up at least 1/3 of the page width. https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/13827267367057-How-can-I-embed-videos-prominently-on-my-site-

Answer (score -2):

The Vimeo player embed has no control over the google video index, that's unique to google and you should reach out to their support channels.

Comment: Google doesn't offer much of any support for indexing and ranking issues.